# %SystemRoot% and C:\WINDOWS in path

Tags: windows-7, windows, path

I have noticed my path variable includes references to the Windows directory in both `%SystemRoot%` and `C:\Windows` forms.

e.g. there exists a `%SystemRoot%\system32` and a `C:\Windows\system32` in the path variable.

- Is it safe to remove one of the forms, and if so, which is it
  preferable to remove?
- Is there any performance gain (no matter how minor) to be obtained
  from doing so?

Comment: The form in which path directories are added is up to the programs which add them. The environment variable form is marginally slower (_very_ marginally), as it adds an environment look-up to the processing, but this is negligible compared with the time taken to search the directories for the file to be run. The environment form has the advantage that the look-up will still work if the disc letter should change (eg on adding another disc), though it is unlikely that the system will run without a lot of other modifications. Otherwise, there are no significant differences between the two forms.

Comment: Run `for %G in ("%path:;=","%") do @echo "%~G"` (paste the code to an open `cmd` prompt). If you can see `%SystemRoot%` in the output then there is something wrong…

Answer (score 1):

1. Removing the hard-coded one and leaving the %SystemRoot% one in will protect you in the rare (and almost unimaginable) instance of your windows being moved to a different drive/folder. I don't know why someone would want to do that, but it's possible, and %SystemRoot% would always run in the right place.

Removing the %SystemRoot% one and leaving the hard-coded one in might be faster in that Windows is not having to decode the %SystemRoot% environment variable into its true value when you check your path. Though if Windows was 'smart', it probably decodes it only once and stores it in memory in its decoded format.

2. The performance gain should not be perceptible, but in theory, having it in there once will prevent it from searching the same folder twice for your executable.  But in practice, we're talking millisecond.

2B) You could perhaps run a timed check of a command that doesn't exist - mash your keyboard - and time how long it takes for the prompt to return.  Then fix the path so only one is in there, and run the test again. Then fix the path so only one is in there -- the OTHER one -- and run that test again. That's your performance gain/loss.

I'd definitely be interested in your findings if you tested this.  The specific timings of a path search using %SystemRoot%, hardcoded, or both together.

But you're not going to be able to perceive it, either way.  In theory, if you were running tons and tons of quick commands, like a script that runs thousands of little utilities that are relatively instant ... Then that additional search time could maybe add up to a second or three :)